# Using php, how to run a function on files names that include spaces?

Tags: php

I am running an ffmpeg function on all files in the the folder that contains a script.

```
foreach (glob("*.{mp4}", GLOB_BRACE) as $named)
{
  $src = substr($named,0,-4);

  MP4ToAnimatedGIF($src, $GIF_SIZE_WIDTHxHEIGHT, $DURATION_SECS, $FIRST_FRAME_NUM, $FRAME_SKIP, $PREROLL_SECS);
}
```

the previous function or this one ($src and $mp4 are the same thing):

```
  @exec("ffmpeg -ss 0:00:$preroll_seconds -i $mp4.mp4 -t 0:0:".($duration_seconds*2)." -s $sizeXxY -f image2 $TMP_DIRECTORY/%03d.png");
```

Are handling the filenames. My problem is that this error's out if the filename has a space.  The issue is that I am talking about 50 files and each has references across a site.  changing the filenames will require a TON more work... Any ideas?

Comment: Try `@exec("ffmpeg -ss 0:00:$preroll_seconds -i '$mp4.mp4' -t 0:0:".($duration_seconds*2)." -s $sizeXxY -f image2 $TMP_DIRECTORY/%03d.png");`

Comment: Also, it's dumb that PHP doesn't have a library function for executing a child process with parameters from an array.

Comment: Have you escaped the spaces? E.g. "`some file.mp4`" should be "`some\ file.mp4`".

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: Kojiro, thanks for the notes, but it actually wiped out part of the filename. Evert, this is what I think I need to do but looking at the docs for escapesshellarg I am not sure how to pass all the files in a folder to it... any help would be greatly appreciated.